# How to search/index dynamic fields

Tags: database, indexing, elasticsearch

How do you index data that's changing every second?  What tools/technologies would you use? A quick example would be Yelp's open now status.  Open now varies per business, and it's determined by the time of the requests.  One second later, a business can switch from open to close, and thus filtered out from the list.

Unlike static fields like names and addresses, open now is dynamic.

Do you think running a cronjob every 5 minutes flipping the open_now status across millions of documents would be a good idea (which obviously makes the open_now status accuracy down to 5 minute increment)?  Or is there something more fancy, like a script that's triggered at the time of requests, and fast enough for it to execute as it performs the search?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand the operation you want optimize. Do you have to update the open_now value or only read a list of open_now values? Are you using a particular DBMS?

Comment: I am not using any particular DBMS.  I am open to any technology/DB that can support the operation.  I am looking for an efficient way of performing search operations where the field that you are searching by have values that are dynamic in nature.  Unlike names or addresses, they rarely gets updated so the DB has the time to index them. But, what about for fields that are constantly updated, and possibly updated every second.  `open_now` status is just an example.

Comment: Ok,in general you don't have to create an index for every field, but only for those you use for data access. It's very difficult optimize access without know which kind of operation  you have to do. E.g. If your query is a select on primary key, almost every DBMS have an index on primary key field and query is optimized. If you are searching on other fields (e.g. city or timestamp) you have to create an index on these fields. If you have to do an update on a tuple dependently by the value of another maybe you should think at a stored procedure and a trigger... You should be more specific.